# How can I connect two different Traefik instances using Docker as the service discovery provider?

Tags: docker, networking, server, dns, traefik

I have two server, which two sever have traefik container, one server is host another is slave server, so that i need to connect that slave server to host server, which i can access the slave traefik from host traefik container,

how to establish a connect between them

Answer (score 0):

You can use traefik endpoints for that.

On your host add the following label:

```
  --providers.docker.endpoint=tcp://docker-slave-server-ip:2375
```

to make both servers aware of each other.

You also might need to configure remote access for Docker daemon, it depends on how you setup your environment.